# Choosing between two completions lists

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm in the process of migrating some tcsh completion settings to zsh and I'm a little lost in the documentation.  What I'd like is to complete an argument in one of two ways.  If the current word to be completed does not contains a `/`, it should be one of a set of strings.  If it does contains a `/`, it should be a directory.

This:

```
_foo() {
    _arguments -C '1:Name:(Name1 Name2 Name3)' '1:Directory:_path_files -/'
}
```

does not work as it isn't allowed to specify twice the same argument.  I played with `_regex_arguments` but I seem to have missed something there, because I got no behavior which made any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with:

```
#compdef foo

_foo() {
     local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
     typeset -A opt_args
     _arguments -C '-a' '-b' '-c' '-d' '1: :->name'
     case $state in
         name)
             case $words[2] in
                 */*)
                     _arguments '*:directory:_path_files -/'
                     ;;
                 *)
                     _arguments '*:name:(Name1 Name2 Name3)'
                     ;;
             esac
     esac
}

_foo "$@"
```

but I'm not sure this is the best solution.  In particular, I copied the usage of `$words` from some examples, but I didn't find it in the documentation.